# Errors while creating master in cluster of kubernetes in lxc container

Tags: kubernetes

I'm setting up a kubernetes cluster using lxc container while I was configuring master node with kubeadm init it is showing the following error:-

```
kubeadm init --apiserver-advertise-address=10.102.126.160 --pod-network-cidr=192.168.0.0/16
[init] Using Kubernetes version: v1.13.1
[preflight] Running pre-flight checks
[preflight] The system verification failed. Printing the output from the verification:
KERNEL_VERSION: 4.15.0-43-generic
DOCKER_VERSION: 18.06.1-ce
DOCKER_GRAPH_DRIVER: overlay2
OS: Linux
CGROUPS_CPU: enabled
CGROUPS_CPUACCT: enabled
CGROUPS_CPUSET: enabled
CGROUPS_DEVICES: enabled
CGROUPS_FREEZER: enabled
CGROUPS_MEMORY: enabled
error execution phase preflight: [preflight] Some fatal errors occurred:
    [ERROR FileContent--proc-sys-net-bridge-bridge-nf-call-iptables]: /proc/sys/net/bridge/bridge-nf-call-iptables does not exist
    [ERROR Swap]: running with swap on is not supported. Please disable swap
    [ERROR SystemVerification]: failed to parse kernel config: unable to load kernel module: "configs", output: "modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod.c:586 kmod_search_moddep() could not open moddep file '/lib/modules/4.15.0-43-generic/modules.dep.bin'\nmodprobe: FATAL: Module configs not found in directory /lib/modules/4.15.0-43-generic\n", err: exit status 1
[preflight] If you know what you are doing, you can make a check non-fatal with `--ignore-preflight-errors=...`
```

Can anyone help me out to solve this issue.

Answer (score 3):

To run kubernetes inside `lxc container` you need to do some configuration first, like there is no `kernel module` in lxc container, so you need to use `overlay` driver for docker. Also, your swap is ON you need to disable it using `swapoff -a`. There are many of these configuration you need to do before installing kubernetes cluster using kubeadm.

Here is the very nice blog explaining step by step configuration in lxc container:

https://medium.com/@kvapss/run-kubernetes-in-lxc-container-f04aa94b6c9c

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as @Prafull Ladha said already, you have to create lxc containers with some config:

- Disable swap
- Use overlay2 driver for docker
- Run containers as privileged

You can see all this stuff in this lxc [profile](https://github.com/debiasej/k8s-lxc/blob/master/lxd-provisioning/profile-config) that you should pass when you create your containers.

`lxc launch images:ubuntu/16.04 CONTAINER_NAME --profile PROFILE_NAME`

But your big big problem is run the Kubelet into a lxc container. Kubelet logs will show something like that:

```
failed to start OOM watcher open /dev/kmsg: no such file or directory
```

If you get this error you should do a little hack because the `/dev/kmsg` character device is not created by default. You can create this device with following command:

`mknod /dev/kmsg c 1 11`

Maybe a kernel image update is needed. You can go through the whole process in these [scripts](https://github.com/debiasej/k8s-lxc/tree/master/ubuntu-cluster) for ubuntu 16.04